# Use CSV file with Names to get ADUser Email Addresses

Tags: powershell, csv

First, I would like to thank you for your help

This is my question
I've got a CSV file with one Line

| DisplayName |
| --- |
| John Doe |
| Jane Doe |

And I would like to use this Names so I get their EmailAdresses from our AD

This is the code

```
Import-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv 
 
$List =  Foreach ($user in $users) {

Get-ADUser -Filter "name -eq '$user.DisplayName'" -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=local' -Properties name, emailAddress | Select-Object Name, emailAddress

}

$List = Export-CSV c:\temp\allinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

But it is not working

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're not assigning your import to anything. So change it to `$users = Import-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv`. And change your foreach loop to the following `Foreach($user in $users.displayname){Get-ADUser -Filter {displayname -match $user}...`

Comment: Change this `-Filter "name -eq '$user.DisplayName'"` for this `-LDAPFilter "(displayName=$($user.DisplayName))"` in addition calling the `-Properties Name` is not needed, `Name` is a default property of `Get-ADUser`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @[Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) said, your code doesn't show you capturing your csv import into a variable. I'm assuming that's a typo/copy issue.

The issue I see in your code is you are referencing a property of the variable, which requires a subexpression

```
$userlist = Import-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv 

$List =  Foreach ($user in $userlist) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "name -eq '$($user.DisplayName)'" -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=local' -Properties emailAddress | Select-Object Name, emailAddress
}

$List | Export-CSV c:\temp\allinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

You could also dereference the property as part of the foreach statement which would make the simple variable expand fine without subexpression.

```
$userlist = Import-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv 

$List =  Foreach ($user in $userlist.Displayname) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "name -eq '$user'" -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=local' -Properties emailAddress | Select-Object Name, emailAddress
}

$List | Export-CSV c:\temp\allinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I tried the first one 

Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:4 char:5
+     Get-ADUser -Filter "name -eq '$($user.DisplayName)'" -SearchBase  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Neither the second solution, gives also an error back

Comment: @ach.ala try the LDAP filter I posted on comments, you're also basing your search on DisplayName not Name. `-LDAPFilter "(displayName=$($user.DisplayName))"`

Comment: Probably have a dirty csv file then. Errant spaces or other characters. You should also replace all single and double quotes with manually typed ones. Sometimes copying/pasting from different forums you get fancy quotes that aren't correct. Here's an image showing how the subexpression is required and will work https://imgur.com/fzq6qT5